# Summarize values in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database that looks as following image shows:

[image: here]

As you can see my structure is **year** **month** and **day** and then what type of workshift it is.

I have this idea that to get the data you select **month** and **year** and then the data should be fetched from children and get summed up.

Comment: How do you plan to sum the data up? firebase doesn't support data aggregation natively yet.

Comment: Ok thats sad. So its not possible to get all values from key "Adblue" for example and then add them up to a total?

Comment: You can get the values alright, but you'll have to do the sum on the client side. So if your values from 'Adblue' has a thousand values, you'll have to grab them all, send them to the client, then process the sum of them all in your code there. Aggregation is a missing feature in Firebase at the moment

Comment: Ok so how do I grab them? Any good way for doing this?

Comment: This might help: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data